# Send signal data from QMainwindow to QDialog

Tags: qt

I am going to send data collected in the QMainWindow to an object of QDialog via signal-slot connections. Here is the relevant code fragment to do this in mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_dialogA_clicked()
{
    if(dialogA==NULL) dialogA =new MyDialog();

    //'this' refers to MainWindow
    connect(this,SIGNAL(sendData(QVector<bool>)), dialogA, SLOT(getData(QVector<bool>)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    dialogA->show();
}
```

However when working with `dialogA`, it seems that the data are not updated properly and the dialog interface becomes `Not responding` after while. I wonder if the signal-slot connection above is right or not, or that is the way to have data communication with a QDiaglog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things...first, switch to the modern method of creating signal/slot connections:

```
connect (this, &MainWindow::sendData, dialogA, &MyDialog::getData, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

If there's something wrong with the definition, using this format allows the compiler to catch it rather than a run-time warning. Assuming the parameters are defined correctly, there's nothing wrong with the "connect" statement except that it's in the wrong place, which is the second issue.

Every time the user clicks, an additional connection is being made between your main window and the dialog. Qt doesn't automatically ensure that only one connection is made between a given signal and slot. It'll create as many as you ask it for. The "connect" call should be part of the "if" block:

```
if (! dialogA) 
{
    dialogA =new MyDialog();
    connect...
}
```

Depending on how much data is in that vector and what the dialog does with it, if you click enough times, it may be that you're just processing the data so many times that everything slows down tremendously.